# which exception will return?

Tags: exception, plsql

View the Exhibit to examine the PL/SQL code.

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  past_due EXCEPTION;
  acct_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    past_due EXCEPTION;
    acct_num NUMBER;
    due_date DATE    := sysdate -1;
    todays_date DATE := sysdate;
  BEGIN
    IF due_date < todays_date THEN
      raise past_due;
    END IF;
  END;
EXCEPTION
WHEN past_due THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('handling past_due exeption.');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('could not recognize rxception.');
END;
```

Which statement is true about the execution of the code?

A. The exception raised in the code is handled by the exception handler for the PAST_DUE
exception.

B. It does not execute because you cannot declare an exception with a similar name in the
subblock.

C. The PAST_DUE exception raised in the subblock causes the program to terminate abruptly
because there is no exception handler in the subblock.

D. The PAST_DUE exception raised by the enclosing block is not propagated to the outer block and it is handled by the WHEN OTHERS exception handler.

in the dumps the answer was C but i think its D

Comment: ohh sorry  i well add the answer now @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(D) is the closest to being correct, but even it's not really right.  The `past_due` exception which is raised in the inner block is NOT the same `past_due` exception as is caught in the outer block.  Thus, the inner block's `past_due` exception is caught by the outer block's `OTHER` handler.  Try running the code and you'll see it prints "could not recognize rxception.".  What's incorrect about answer (D) is that it says that "...the PAST_DUE exception...is not propagated to the outer block...".  This is wrong - the exception *is* propagated to the outer block but as there's no specific handler for it (nor can there be as the context in which the exception was declared is not available) it's handled by the `WHEN OTHERS...` handler.  Thus, in my opinion NONE of the answers is correct.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: What should I do to study for the exam if the answers are not clear :(

@Bob Jarvis

Comment: I'd take this study question to the instructor and tell him about the problems with it.  Hopefully he'll be open to a reasoned discussion of the issues or, if all else fails, you'll understand how he wants the question answered even if that answer isn't entirely correct.

Comment: +1. D is also wrong because it refers to "The PAST_DUE exception *raised by the enclosing block*" - the enclosing block is the outer block, which means D is referring to the outermost PAST_DUE exception, which is never raised by this code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As per me the answer is C because the Exception you are calling is not present in the block so will not be able to search for it and wont be able to raise it and will give some error.

Comment: but i try it in sql developer and its work like D @Harshit

Comment: FWIW when I first (quickly) read through the question I thought, "The answer is obviously A". I had to **run the code** to realize my error.  This is a made-up academic question which IMO is worse than useless - not only does it have like-named exceptions defined at multiple levels in the program, but if (as indicated by OP) the "correct" answer is considered to be (C) then the "correct" answer is not only flat-out WRONG, but provides a poor example. IMO exceptions are global resources which should not be redefined at multiple levels. Share and enjoy.